# Google Maps API on Localhost

Tags: google-maps

I got a Google Maps API key that I want to use for both localhost as well as production. Via the API console, one can add referrers, which works great with my site once it's live.
I am having trouble allowing it to accept localhost, however. I don't want to just turn off key restriction for obvious reasons. I feel like my referrers should be:

```
*.mydomain.com/* //This works
*.localhost:3000/*  //This doesn't, nor does any combination of many other localhost things I've tried.
```

Is there a special syntax for localhost, or does localhost just not work?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Here is a list of other things I've tried to no avail:

```
localhost*
localhost/*
*localhost*
*localhost/*
*.localhost*
*.localhost:3000/*
*.127.0.0.1:3000/*
```

Comment: Have you tried using "http://localhost" or "http://localhost:[PORT_NUMBER]"?

Comment: You mean without stars? Yes. That was the first thing I tried (though did not list it).